# Toyota Corolla 2006 Under dash Fuse list abbreviation

Tags: toyota, corolla, fuse, fuse-panel

I am trying to replace the Toyota Corolla 2006 fuse but can't understand the abbreviations:

- P/W
- AM2
- AM1
- ECU-IG
- INV
- P/POINT
- ECU-B
- CIG
- GAUGE
- OBD

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah most of them don't make a lick of sense:

> AM2
>
> AM1

These are for the ignition switch.

> P/W

Power windows

> ECU-IG

Main EFI relay, ECU, various sensors.. lots of important things basically.

> INV

Inverter

> P/POINT

12v Power outlet (the one in the back)

> ECU-B

Daytime Running Lights

> CIG

Power outlet (in the front)/cigarette lighter, stereo, clock (possibly some more things depending on options)

> GAUGE

Dashboard, HVAC controls (and various other gubbins)

> OBD

On-Board Diagnostics port